# add values in a 2 dimensional array using dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c, arrays, memory, dynamic, allocation

Given this task:

> Write a program that allocates the necessary amount of memory for storing the elements from two `[m x n]` integer matrices.

I don't know how to allocate memory to 2 Dimensional arrays.
I read some examples but I don't get it.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define DIM 10


void main()
{
    int **m, *n;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int diml, dimc;;
    puts("Introduceti dimensiunea matricelor(linii|coloane)");
    scanf("%d%d", &diml, &dimc);
    m = (int**)malloc(dimc*sizeof(int));
    puts("Introduceti elementele primei matrici:");
    for (j = 0;j < dimc;j++)
    {
        m[i] = (int *)malloc(diml*(sizeof(int)));
    }
    for (j = 0;j < dimc;j++)
    {
        for (i = 0;i < diml;i++)
        {
            printf("tab[%d][%d]= ", j + 1, i + 1);
            scanf("%*d", m[j][i]);

        }
    }
    _getch();
}
```

My program crash after I enter the first line.

```
Introduceti dimensiunea matricelor(linhi I coloane)
3
3
Introduceti elementele primei matrici:
ab[1][1]= 2
ab[1][2]= 1
ab[1][3]= 2
ab[2][1]=

Problema 3.exe has stopped working
A problem caused the program to stop working correctly.
Windows  will  closethe program and notify you if a solution is
available.
```

Comment: `m = (int**)malloc(dimc*sizeof(int));` --> `m = malloc(dimc*sizeof(int*));`

Comment: 1) `m = (int**)malloc(dimc*sizeof(int));` --> `m = (int**)malloc(dimc*sizeof(int*));` 2) `m[i] = (int *)malloc(diml*(sizeof(int)));` --> `m[j] = (int *)malloc(diml*(sizeof(int)));` 3)`scanf("%*d", m[j][i]);` --> `scanf("%d", &m[j][i]);`

Comment: Do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C. And there is no 2D array in your code! To alloc a 2D array, use `int (*m)[DIMX_CONSTANT] = malloc(sizeof(*m) * y);`

Comment: he/she will not be able to remove this if it will be answer.

Comment: Thank you guys for answering.  @BLUEPIXY - Thank you sir, I followed your advice. My program works fine now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Avoid the mistake of allocating using the wrong size by allocating based on the size of the *object* and not the size of *type*.  If the `sizeof(int)` was less then `sizeof(int *)`, this would explain OP's problem.

   ```
   // m = (int**)malloc(dimc*sizeof(int));   // Original
   // m = (int**)malloc(dimc*sizeof(int *)); // corrected type
   // m = malloc(dimc*sizeof(int *));        // cast not needed
   m = malloc(sizeof *m * dimc);             // best : sizeof object
   ```
2. Use correct index `j` vs. `i` [@BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34516014/add-values-in-a-2-dimensional-array-using-dynamic-memory-allocation#comment56773459_34516014).  This is certainly an issue for OP.

   ```
   for (j = 0;j < dimc;j++) {
     // m[i] = (int *)malloc(diml*(sizeof(int)));
     m[j] = malloc(sizeof *(m[j]) * diml);
   ```
3. Insure compiler warnings are fully enabled - it should have caught this one.

   ```
   // scanf("%*d", m[j][i]);
   scanf("%d", &m[j][i]);
   ```
4. Suggest checking the results of `malloc()` and `scanf()`.

   ```
   #include <stdlib.h>

   m[j] = malloc(sizeof *(m[j]) * diml);
   if (m[j] == NULL && diml != 0)) {
     fprintf(stderr", "Out of memory\n");
     return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }

   if (scanf("%d", &m[j][i]) != 1) {
     fprintf(stderr", "Non-numeric input\n");
     return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }
   ```
5. `main()` should return `int`.

   ```
   #include <stdlib.h>
   int main(void) {
     ...
     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
   }
   ```
6. When promoting, insure output gets printed and is not buffered.  Use `fflush()` or end the prompt with `'\n'`.

   ```
      printf("tab[%d][%d]= ", j + 1, i + 1);
      fflush(stdout);  // add
      scanf(...
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You should allocate like this at first:

```
m = (int**)malloc(dimc*sizeof(int*));
```

After that you allocate like that:

```
m[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
```